# Android: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, xml

A layout that used to work now does not. Its a relative layout with a horizontal scrollview, but when I created this activity I messed up the layout order completely and now it does not work. I cannot figure out why I get this error and my XML code is a complete mess and I do apologize for the chaos. If anyone could explain what the problem is and how I go about fixing it, I would appreciate it.

XML CODE:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_rear_gunner"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:focusable="true"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.mr_br.ibcc_bomber_command.rear_gunner">


<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:fillViewport="true"
>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/enemy2"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/enemy2" android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/nightsky3"/>
</HorizontalScrollView>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/item_frame"
    android:layout_width="2000dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.mr_br.ibcc_bomber_command.rear_gunner"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="36sp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/score"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="43dp" android:layout_marginStart="43dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp" android:focusable="false" android:text="Score:"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textColorLink="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="46sp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Health"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/score" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/score"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/enemy2" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/enemy2"
        android:text="TextView" android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textColorLink="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="46sp"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPilot"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="pilotBonus"
        android:text="Call Pilot Maneuver (Right)" android:layout_below="@+id/powerUps"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnPilotL" android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnPilotL"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPilotL"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="11dp" android:onClick="pilotBonus"
        android:text="Call Pilot Maneuver (Left)" android:layout_below="@+id/btnPilot"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ammo"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="Ammunition:"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textColorLink="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="46sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="49dp" android:layout_marginEnd="49dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/powerUps" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/reinforce3"
        android:layout_width="150dp" android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:scaleX="-1" android:visibility="invisible"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/bomber_neutral_info" android:layout_above="@+id/powerUps"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/reinforce1"
        android:layout_width="150dp" android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" android:scaleX="-1"
        android:visibility="invisible" app:srcCompat="@drawable/bomber_neutral_info"
        android:layout_below="@+id/score" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/reinforce2"
        android:layout_width="150dp" android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:scaleX="-1"
        android:visibility="invisible" app:srcCompat="@drawable/bomber_neutral_info"
        android:layout_below="@+id/reinforce1" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/enemyblah"
        android:layout_width="150dp" android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:visibility="invisible" app:srcCompat="@drawable/bomber_neutral_info"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/reinforce1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/reinforce1" android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/reinforce1"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/enemy4"
        android:layout_width="150dp" android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:visibility="invisible" app:srcCompat="@drawable/bomber_neutral_info"
        android:layout_below="@+id/enemy2" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/enemy2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/enemy2" android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="26dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/powerUps"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="Support Calls Avaliable:"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark" android:textColorLink="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp" android:layout_below="@+id/enemy3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnPilot" android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnPilot"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnReinforce"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="opBonus" android:text="Operator Request Support"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" android:layout_below="@+id/ammo"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/enemy2" android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/enemy2"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ammoR"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="Ammo" android:text="Ammo Request Support"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnReinforce"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnReinforce" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/enemy2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/enemy2" android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="17dp"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/enemy5"
        android:layout_width="150dp" android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:visibility="invisible" app:srcCompat="@drawable/bomber_neutral_info"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ammo" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ammoR"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/ammoR" android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="19dp"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/enemy6"
        android:layout_width="150dp" android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:visibility="invisible" app:srcCompat="@drawable/bomber_neutral_info"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/enemy2" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnReinforce"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btnReinforce" android:layout_marginRight="23dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/enemy3"
        android:layout_width="150dp" android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp" android:visibility="invisible"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/bomber_neutral_info"
        android:layout_below="@+id/enemy2" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/enemy6"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/enemy6"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/enemy2"
        android:layout_width="300dp" android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp" android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
        android:visibility="invisible" app:srcCompat="@drawable/bomber_neutral_info"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/enemyblah" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnReinforce"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnReinforce"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/warning"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:textColorLink="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="46sp" android:layout_above="@+id/reinforce3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:visibility="invisible"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: A circular reference is one where the resolution cannot finish. e.g. Something like saying A is before B and B is before A. I'd suggest removing each view on it's own (i.e. remove a view test, then add it back in and remove the next). When the check works it is likely that the issue is with the removed view. beat me to it and I'll give you an upvote :)

Comment: show us the error you get to help you.

Comment: @MikeT is giving you a really good way to learn how to solve this sort of problem yourself if you come to it again. I encourage you to take their advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your outer relativelayout's imageview depending on enemy2(which is inside inner relativelayout).  This is the problem

Comment: I got the same problem, because I  used the Design UI to delete a layout_below attribute of a WebView but it didn't deleted the attribute. So if do you have to remove an attribute from a component, I suggest you do it from the Code View UI. 
Then reading this answer I succeeded to figure out my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I see one point of concern where it looks like btnPilot relies on the position of btnPilotL which relies on btnPilot. This is probably one of possibly multiple circular references.

Answer (score 0):

I took your advice and began taking out the views 1 by one, the problem was with the enemy1 view. For some reason, I believe this was enemy2 but another activity had changed this when I automatically updated XML references, I changed the ID to something different and the layout works again. Thank you for the advice, I also have a better understanding to what exactly a Circular dependency error is.